# How to retrieve EPPO Database info via POST?

Tags: r, post

I can retrieve [EPPO DB](https://data.eppo.int/documentation/rest) info from GET requests.
I am looking for help to retrieve the info from POST requests.
[Example code and other info in the linked Rmarkdown HTMP output](https://rpubs.com/scotti/EPPO_POST_request_question)

As suggested, I have gone trough the https://httr.r-lib.org/ site.
Interesting. I followed the links to https://httr.r-lib.org/articles/api-packages.html and then to https://cdn.zapier.com/storage/learn_ebooks/e06a35cfcf092ec6dd22670383d9fd12.pdf.
I suppose that the arguments for the POST() function should be (more or less) as follows, but yet the response is always 404

```r
url = "https://data.eppo.int/api/rest/1.0/"
config = list(authtoken=my_authtoken)
body = list(intext = "Fraxinus anomala|Tobacco ringspot virus|invalide name|Sequoiadendron giganteum")
encode = "json"
#handle = ???
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
How do I find the missing pieces?

Comment: I suggest starting with the package vignettes, available at https://httr.r-lib.org/ (and [`?POST`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/POST.html)).

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit tricky:

1. You need to use correct url with name of the service from https://data.eppo.int/documentation/rest, e.g. to use *Search preferred names from EPPOCodes list*:

```
    url = "https://data.eppo.int/api/rest/1.0/tools/codes2prefnames"
```

2. Authorization should be passed to body:

```
body = list(authtoken = "yourtoken", intext = "BEMITA")
```

So, if you want to check names for two eppocodes: XYLEFA and BEMITA the code should look like:

```
httr::POST(
  url = "https://data.eppo.int/api/rest/1.0/tools/codes2prefnames",
  body = list(authtoken = "yourtoken", intext = "BEMITA|XYLEFA") 
)
```

Nonetheless, I would also recommend you to just use the [pestr](https://github.com/mczyzj/pestr) package. However, to find eppocodes it uses SQLite database under the hood instead of EPPO REST API. Since the db is not big itself (circa 40MB) this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I added my test of your suggestion as a new answer. 
For sure the SQLite file that 'pestr' produces is the handiest solution but it is off-line.
With an on-line solution (like via POST) up to date response is assured.
Roberto

Comment: I would not be so sure that the on-line solution is more up to date than SQL solutions. All in all the API is just an interface to query EPPO database. I am not sure if SQLite version is updated at the same time that ordinary SQL, but if you need always the most recent you should check `log-shipping` at eppo database.

Comment: With 'update is assured' I am actually just mentioning the obvious: a locally downloaded DB will be sooner or later outdated by its online reference.
You mention the existence of a <log-shipping> at eppo. I searched for it but could not find it. Is it possible to have more directions or a link? Many thanks

Comment: https://data.eppo.int/documentation/logshipping

Comment: The downside of using EPPO rest API is that it does not support partial matching, which you can do using pester. E.g. using `POST/tools/names2codes` with phrase *Fraxinus anomal* will result in `"response": "Fraxinus anoma;****NOT FOUND*****"` . So downloading updated SQL db even on a daily basis is small cost for much more flexible ability to find what you need. Especially that it is easy to set up a script that will do this automatically.

Comment: I get your point and agree!

Answer (score 0):

I found the easy way following a suggestion in the DataCamp course:
"To find an R client for an API service search 'CRAN '"
I found the 'pestr' package that gives great access to EPPO database.
I still do not know how to use the POST() function myself. Any hint on that side is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to loop over names to get EPPO-codes. Whit minor adjustments this also works for distribution and other information in the EPPO DB

```
# vector of species names
host_name <- c("Fraxinus anomala", "Tobacco ringspot virus", "invalide name", 
"Sequoiadendron giganteum") 

EPPO_key <- "enter personal key"

# EPPO url 
path_eppo_code <- "https://data.eppo.int/api/rest/1.0/tools/names2codes"

# epty list 
my_list <- list() 

for (i in host_name) {

# POST request on eppo database
response <- httr::POST(path_eppo_code, body=list(authtoken=EPPO_key, 
intext=i))

# get EPPO code
pest_eppo_code <- strsplit(httr::content(response)[[1]], ";")[[1]][2]
 
# add to list
my_list[[i]] <- pest_eppo_code  
}

# list to data frame 
data <- plyr::ldply(my_list)
```